# Change text message "Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time"

Tags: shipping, text

I want to change this text at the checkout page, once no shipping method can select. I did try to override the core file seems not working, and I did change at core file, seems not working, am I editing the wrong file? 
app/design/frontend/testing/ABC/Magento_Checkout/web/template/shipping.html
also I did try to change vendor/magento/moudle-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/cart/shipping-rates.html

even I did scan the text over the complete folder, still can't find anything else.

Please help

Comment: Please run setup upgrade command once after file changes and then check your changes once in private window. Hope this will work for you!

Comment: Is there any impact if I run this on production server?

Comment: No, run all commands there in production mode. Upgrade, compile, deploy once and check.

Comment: oh god, after setup upgrade....all the page show this.....RuntimeException: The path "/var/www/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Session/Generic/Interceptor.php.87412" cannot be renamed into "/var/www/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Session/Generic/Interceptor.php" Warning!rename(/var/www/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Session/Generic/Interceptor.php.87412,/var/www/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Session/Generic/Interceptor.php): No such file or directory Class Magento\Framework\Session\Generic\Interceptor generation error: The requested class did not generate properly....etc

Comment: Set permission 777 in var pub and generated directory